# In Regular React how to dismiss mobile keyboards on submit or 'enter' key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to find this answer, but all the other questions I have found are React Native.

```
`handleEnter(e){
    if(e.key == 'Enter'){
        //REMOVE KEYBOARD
    }
}`
```

Also my input is a text search. So I want the keyboard to hide so users can see the results that come up.

Comment: How are the user supposed to write if you, for instance, hide the keyboard ? You might force a blur as the answer below suggested, but this is extremely dirty from the UX perspective.

Answer (score 7):

`e.target` is the focused `input` or `textarea` where the user is writhing. When he click on `Enter` the focused `input` became unfocused and so the keyboard disappear

```
handleEnter(e){
    if(e.key == 'Enter'){
        e.target.blur();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Justcode there isn't so mush to explain. `e.target` is the focused `input` or `textarea` where the user is writhing. When he click on `Enter` the focused `input` became unfocused and so the keyboard disappear

Comment: Yes, Just remove `there isn't so mush to explain` from your comment, and all rest of the text to your answer :D