# How to hide a soft keyboard in mobile view reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

After clicking search button i perform this function. So in mobile view after typing in search bar when i hit Search button in mobile the keypad stays on. how to hide after search is performed.

```
 const onSearch = async (e) => {
    if(e.which === 13 && searchKeyword !== null || e.type === 'click' && searchKeyword !== null){
       dispatch(searchProduct(searchKeyword))
          setTimeout(() => {
            props.history.push({
              pathname: '/searchresults',
              state: {from: searchKeyword}
            })
          }, 500)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Keyboard.dismiss function!

```
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native'

const onSearch = async (e) => {
    /* Function logic */
    Keyboard.dismiss()
}
```

Comment: I asked it for reactjs

Comment: Oh sorry, you tagged it as a react-native problem, I believe someone already answered this for regular reactjs though, here's a link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53006913/in-regular-react-how-to-dismiss-mobile-keyboards-on-submit-or-enter-key)